# Use of quotation marks in example conversations

Tags: punctuation

I am trying to understand if a hypothetical conversation in an article should be treated as a quote ie have quotation marks surrounding it.
For example. When talking about whether or not it is a good restaurant it's not advisable to say: what a dump, it would be better to think of a concrete critisicm and use that: the kitchen was visibly dirty.

Any ideas welcome, thank you

Comment: This appears to be just asking for opinions... so I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of style and you should be guided by your manual of style. I use the *Chicago Manual of Style*, which advises the following:

- Use quotes for direct discourse even if hypothetical:

  > I was going to say, "Even the cockroaches looked hungry, but upon second thought, that's not true."
- Do not use quotes for indirect discourse:

  > Concrete criticism must say that the kitchen is visibly dirty.
- Do not use quotes for rhetorical or hypothetical questions:

  > One might be tempted ask Who would eat in this dump? but don't include that in a review.
- Do not use quotes for *yes*, *no*, and other short responses unless they're part of quoted conversation:

  > We're at the restaurant. Don't ask why. Next time when I ask if we should come here just say no.

Comment: That usefully addresses several questions. Does it address internal dialogue separately?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that definitely calls for quotation marks, from "what a dump...".

Even thoughts employ them, where they form a literally stated record. "Where would this road take him" thought Mike.

Comment: Although I agree and +1, it is worth noting that many authors today put so-called internal dialog in italics rather than quotes.  *Hmm, will this comment get any votes?* cobaltduck wondered.